# Vertical scroll for sidebarpanel in SHINY

Tags: r, sidebar, shinyapps

I would like to lock the sidebar so that it is always there as I scroll down the mainpanel and I have achieved it by adding:

```
 style = "position: fixed; width: 25%",
```

after sidebarPanel.

HOWEVER, I have many input sliders and when the sidebar locks I can't see all of them. This is why I would like to add a vertical scroll bar in the sidebar.

I am aware that this is feasible in ShinyDashboard by adding:

```
dashboardSidebar(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                      .sidebar { height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto; }
                      " )
      )
    ),
```

but I don't have a dashboardSidebar, I have something like:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(

        # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
        sidebarPanel(
...
...
)
        mainPanel(
...)
)
```

Could someone help me please? I DON'T have a Dashboard and I don't want to change it to Dashboard.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to add `style = "height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;"` after `sidebarPanel`? What is the problem?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent That combined with position:fixed; worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add this line of code after sidebarPanel

```
style = "position: fixed; height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;"
```